# How to get the text from the last span with class 'star fill'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape a website using `BeautifulSoup`. and I am having trouble getting the ratings from a review. They are stored in a table that has a `span` tag with last class `'star fill'`.

```
seatcomfort = Ratings.select_one('tr:has(td:first-child:-soup-contains("Seat Comfort")) td.review-rating-stars.stars, span.star fill')

Value For Money = Ratings.select_one('tr:has(td:first-child:-soup-contains("Seat Comfort")) td.review-rating-stars.stars, span.star fill')

Inflight Entertainment = Ratings.select_one('tr:has(td:first-child:-soup-contains("Seat Comfort")) td.review-rating-stars.stars, span.star fill')

print (seatcomfort)

<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star">2</span><span class="star">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>
<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star">2</span><span class="star">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>

print (Value For Money)

<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>
<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star">2</span><span class="star">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>

print (Inflight Entertainment)

<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>
<td class="review-rating-stars stars"><span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star">2</span><span class="star">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span></td>
```

I hope to get 1 for `Value for money` , 2 for for `value for money`, and 3 for `inflight entertainment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question needs some improvment (fromatting, initial HTML or url) so this should only point into direction.

Select your elements with class `star fill` and get `len()` of `ResultSet`

```
len(soup.select('.review-rating-stars span.star.fill'))
```

or extract the text of the last element:

```
soup.select('.review-rating-stars span.star.fill')[-1].text
```

To store structured data use a `dict`:

```
{e.td.text:len(e.select('.star.fill')) for e in soup.select('table.review-ratings tr')}
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<table class="review-ratings">
<tbody><tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header food-beverages">Food &amp; Beverages</td>
    <td class="review-rating-stars stars">
        <span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span>                                              </td>
</tr>
                                            <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header inflight-entertainment">Inflight Entertainment</td>
    <td class="review-rating-stars stars">
        <span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span>                                              </td>
</tr>
                                            <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header seat-comfort">Seat Comfort</td>
    <td class="review-rating-stars stars">
        <span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span>                                              </td>
</tr>
                                            <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header staff-service">Staff Service</td>
    <td class="review-rating-stars stars">
        <span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span>                                              </td>
</tr>
                                            <tr>
    <td class="review-rating-header value-for-money">Value for Money</td>
    <td class="review-rating-stars stars">
        <span class="star fill">1</span><span class="star fill">2</span><span class="star fill">3</span><span class="star">4</span><span class="star">5</span>                                              </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

{e.td.text:len(e.select('.star.fill')) for e in soup.select('table.review-ratings tr')}
```

##### Output

```
{'Food & Beverages': 3,
 'Inflight Entertainment': 3,
 'Seat Comfort': 3,
 'Staff Service': 3,
 'Value for Money': 3}
```